# App Crashes when trying to add cells to tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am using an NSMutableArray to populate my tableView.The array's name is `cells`. I have a button that adds cells, but when i press the button, the app crashes. The code in my button is:

```
- (IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender {
[cart.cells addObject:@"1"];
[cart.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

this button is on a seperate page from the table view, so `cart` is referring to the tableView page. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There's nothing glaringly obviously wrong there.  But what error/crash do you see, and at what line of code.

Comment: Well in the console im getting a message saying: `** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BlackFacePlateViewControlller outlet1]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6865090'
*** Call stack at first throw:` and the error is on the `int revtal` line in main. And the error says:Thread1: program recieved signal sigabrt` THanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message means that someone is trying to call a method named `outlet1` that has no argument (note the missing colon) while your method's signature is `outlet1:`. You have probably missed the colon of the selector when adding the target/action to your button.

Comment: i had my outlets messed up in IB! Also, when i press the button and try to see the newly added cell on the second view, there is still no cell. Does anybody know why this is? Thanks for the help

Comment: So do u mean that its not crashing anymore and the problem right now is the added cell is not showing up?